# Can we combine 2 font styles together in Java?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel

I am trying to change the font of a `JLabel` so it is both `BOLD` and `ITALIC`, but it seems there's no static field defined to do so. How can we combine two styles so we can have a bold, italic font?

This code will do it with just bold by using the static field `BOLD`, but there's no field defined for both bold and italic:

```
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
label = new JLabel ("New Image") ;
label.setFont(font);
label.setForeground(Color.Gray.darker());
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, the [`style`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) parameter is seen as a bitmask:

```
new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 12)
```

Comment: Bitwise "or" | is preferred over addition ("+")

Comment: @Hovercraft: Agreed. As @Paŭlo comments, `+`, `|` and `^` are equivalent in this context. `+` may be slightly more readable, but that may be the Pascal talking. Too bad `EnumSet` was a later addition.

Comment: @trashgod: it works the same here, but using + is not a good habit to get into as it may not work later, for instance if the code adds a bitmap into one that already had this bit map (a realistic situation at times). For instance if I had a myFontStyles variable that I want to make sure used italics, `myFontStyles | Font.ITALIC` alwys will work whereas addition can spell disaster.

Comment: @trashgod Why such non obvious api? And no additional setters for italic or bold on existing Font object.

Comment: @SašaŠijak: [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) might have been a better representation, but it came some years later; sorry for the delay responding.

Answer (score 12):

[From the API documentation of this constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29):

> Parameters:
>
> - ...
> - `style` - the style constant for the Font. The style argument is an integer bitmask that may be `PLAIN`, or a bitwise union of `BOLD` and/or `ITALIC` (for example, `ITALIC` or `BOLD|ITALIC`). If the style argument does not conform to one of the expected integer bitmasks then the style is set to `PLAIN`.
> - ...

Thus, use

```
new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 12);
```

here.

Comment: @trashgod: There is really no difference between `+`, `|` and `^` in the case of disjunct bits like here. (ITALIC = 2 = 2¹, BOLD = 1 = 2⁰.)

Comment: But it's not a good habit to get into as you will easily run into situations where it does make a difference as noted in my comment above.