# setting the font name, style and size for the jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have a pop up to select font for the user . I have listed them in 3 JList. From the 3 list they will select the "Font Family", "Font Size" and "Font Style".
I have this code:

```
Fonts f= new Fonts();
int result=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,f,"Fonts",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    String fontium=f.getFonts();
    int size=Integer.parseInt(f.getSizes());
    String style=f.getStyle();
    System.out.println("you selected \n Font:" + fontium + "\n size:" + size + "\n style:" + style);
Font font=new Font(fontium, style, size);
textArea1.setFont(font);

}
```

The problem i'm having is style comes in string but style accepts int. How can i solve this.

Comment: Use a `JComboBox` or `JToggleButton`s to allow the user to select the style(s) they want. This will allow you to make the `int` values to your UI values

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer how to do it using JList

Comment: You create a custom object which represents both the human representation (ie Bold) and the int value, this way you can add the object to the JList, use a custom cell renderer to present the "name" the user and you can get the int value from the selected item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know what `Fonts` class does and what the `style` value returns.

There are 2 possible results of these.

- If `style` value returns `"0"`or `"1"` or `"2"`, then you can convert the value to String just like this:

  ```
  String style=f.getStyle();
  int fontStyle = Integer.parseInt(style);
  ```
- If style value returns `styleName` such as `"bolditalic"` or `"italic"` or `"bold"` or `"plain"`, then you need to control the value like this

  ```
  int fontStyle = 0;
  if (style.equals("bolditalic")) {
      fontStyle = Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC;
  } else if (style.equals("italic")) {
      fontStyle = Font.ITALIC;
  } else if (style.equals("bold")) {
      fontStyle = Font.BOLD;
  } else if (style.equals("plain")) {
      fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
  }
  ```

Comment: Style can return a bit wised value (bold+italic)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345162/why-are-bold-italic-not-working/32345295#32345295)

Comment: Note in particular how @MadProgrammer's [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345162/why-are-bold-italic-not-working/32345295#32345295) uses `deriveFont()`.